# how to remove given error " Failed to instantiate module app due to:"

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to make simple app in angular js .I includes js files in my project. But I am getting this error

```
   **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.stationselect due to:
TypeError: $urlRouterProvider.state is not a function
    at routeChange (http://localhost:63342/www/js/stationselect/router.js:9:28)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12877:17)
    at runInvokeQueue (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12783:35)
    at http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12792:11
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:9015:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12773:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12790:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:9015:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12773:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12699:11)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=app.stationselect&…(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63342%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A12699%3A11)
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:8755:12)
    at http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12812:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:9015:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12773:5)
    at http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12790:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:9015:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12773:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:12699:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:10137:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:63342/www/lib/ionic.bundle.js:10158:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20…(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63342%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10158%3A12)**
```

actually I check

when I remove one script from index.html it remove that error
script is this

```
<script src="js/stationselect/router.js"></script>
```

But when I include again it show again given error

I don't what thing I write wrong ? Actually in my app there is some directory so I am not able to use fiddle .I will share my code with you

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip?dl=0

here is my script code

```
(function(){

  'use strict'

    angular.module('app.stationselect').config(routeChange);

    routeChange.$inject=['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'];
    function routeChange($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.state('selectstation',{
            url:'/selectstation',
            controller:'selectStation',
            templateUrl:'js/stationselect/partial/home.html'
        })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/selectstation');
    }
})();
```

Comment: Could it be that you should have `angular.module('app.stationselect', ['ui.router'])` to create the module? Otherwise, angular expects to be able to find an existing module named `app.stationselect`

Comment: Also, providing the full error message (instead of the truncated version) would help debug this faster

Comment: @Phil checking I will try.please check update..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should have

```
angular.module('app.stationselect', ['ui.router']).config(...)
```

if you're creating the `app.stationselect` module there.

When you only provide one argument to `angular.module()` (ie, the module name), Angular attempts to retrieve it from the module registry.

If you've already created your module elsewhere, ignore the above.

---

Also, `.state` is a method of `$stateProvider`, not `$urlRouterProvider`. This is what's causing the error message.